# Combining TimeItem and DateItem values

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt, gwt-rpc, gwt-ext

I have to combine the time value for TimeItem and date value from DateItem in smartgwt.In output I want the date object for java.util.Date.I tried to combine these two.I couldnot do that.

Sample code is :

```
DateItem date=new DateItem();
TimeItem time=new TimeItem();
DynamicForm form=new DynamicForm();
form.setFields(date,time);

// java.util.Date selectedDate= ? Here I need the output
```

Can anyone help on this? thanks

Comment: Did you get answer of this question. I have DateField and TimeField I want to combine them and make a java.sql.Date object. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but this is my educated guess:

You can set the dateItem.setInputFormat(...) and dateItem.setDisplayFormat(...) using a date format that also includes time.